# How to make a get inside a form button OnPressed() in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, flutter-web

I want to make a get call inside the `onPressed` function of a form.

I have a service that make a post and return the `response.body`:

```
    Future<String> getItems() async {
        final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('$baseUrl/edicios'));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return response.body;
        }
    }
```

And here in the `onPressed` we call that function:

```
    onPressed: () {
      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
        futureString = resource.MyHttpService().getItems();
        print(futureString);
    }
```

I have read the flutter doc to make gets and posts but it's confusing. If someone can just explain how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your getItems() function is a future, you will need to await the response before printing it. This also means that your onPressed function needs to use the 'async' keyword:

```
onPressed: () async {
      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
        futureString = await resource.MyHttpService().getItems();
        print(futureString);
    }
```

You can read more about [async/await here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).